# Linux directory shortcut path for browser

Tags: apache, ubuntu, server, path

In Ubuntu, more specifically apache, is there such a function as to create a folder in the public directory which serves files from private folder with the url path?

Directory setup:

```
- public_html
  + .htaccess
  + foo@ # shortcut to ../foo/public
  + index.html
- foo
  + private
  - public
    + index.html
```

The URL looks like this

```
https://website.bar/foo
```

The server would serve

```
/public_html/../foo/public
```

Comment: Function?  No, use command line to create directories and setup ownership.

Comment: @Nic3500 really I meant "way"... I will look into the ownership. Thank you

Comment: Make sure you put `Options +FollowSymLinks` on directory public_html.  Otherwise the symbolic link will be ignored.